# PHP SimpleXML parse differently depending on line break

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, line-breaks

I want to parse XML string using SimpleXML on PHP.

```
$xml = '<root><case1><name> </name></case1><case2><name></name></case2><case3><name>ukits</name></case3></root>';

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$content = simplexml_load_string($xml);

if ($content === false) {
    libxml_clear_errors();
}

print_r($content);

$content = objectToArray($content);

print_r($content);

function objectToArray($obj) {
    if (is_object($obj)) { $obj = (array) $obj; }

    if (count($obj) == 0) { $obj = ''; }

    if (is_array($obj)) {
        $new = array();
        foreach ($obj as $key => $val) {
            $new[$key] = objectToArray($val);
        }
    } else {
        $new = $obj;
    }
    return $new;
}
```

This code returns:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [case1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [name] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [0] =>  
                )
        )
    [case2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                )
        )
    [case3] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [name] => ukits
        )
)
Array
(
    [case1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [0] =>  
                )
        )
    [case2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )
    [case3] => Array
        (
            [name] => ukits
        )
)
```

There seems to be 2 unexpected problems. In case1, **name tag has a OBJECT child** (not spaced string). In case2, **case2 tag has a numeric array**.

But, if the XML string contains line break or space after 'name' tag, the result is different. like this:

```
$xml = '<root><case1><name> </name>
</case1><case2><name></name>
</case2><case3><name>ukits</name></case3></root>';
```

The same code returns:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [case1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [name] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                )
        )
    [case2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [name] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                )
        )
    [case3] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [name] => ukits
        )
)
Array
(
    [case1] => Array
        (
            [name] => 
        )
    [case2] => Array
        (
            [name] => 
        )
    [case3] => Array
        (
            [name] => ukits
        )
)
```

This result is that I want to get.

The point is WHY the results of "same structured XML strings" are differnt depend on line break.

And how do I do If I want to get what I want like second result?
(An input string have to contain no line break.)

Here is my configuration:

```
CentOS 6.7
PHP 5.4.45
SimpleXML Revision $Id: 16070fc92ad6f69cebb2d52ad3f02794f833ce39 $
libxml2 Version 2.7.6
```

Comment: "case2 tag has a numeric array" - that's really a bug, see https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=66084 , using a php version without that bug you consistently get `[case1] => [name] =>  [0] => ()` and `[case2] => [name] => ()`, even with the linebreak after `</name>`. But I have no idea how to get SimpleXML/libxml to treat the whitespace within `<name>` as insignificant and remove the text node completely. My only hunch (provide a dtd and declaring name as #PCDATA only) didn't work.

Comment: If you ignore the output of `print_r`, and just use the data how you want, you'll probably find it's not a problem. SimpleXML can't ignore the whitespace, because that's not how XML works, but the clever thing is that you don't have to care - if you want to echo the content of the `<name>` element, you just `echo $foo->name;` and it will do the right thing.

Comment: @VolkerK It's weird that the bug reported long time ago, my PHP still has it. Thanks anyway. very helpful.

Comment: @IMSoP As you told, SimpleXML object returns correct data. But I designed my API will accept both of XML and JSON. so I cannot help converting XML object to array for processing data. Thank you! also very helpful.

Comment: As a makeshift, I added the line,
    `$xml = str_replace("><", ">\n<", $xml);` bebore  `$content = simplexml_load_string($xml);`
I'm not sure where It has some side effects or not.

Comment: You still don't need to convert blindly to an array - somewhere you must have a foreach loop or similar over that array, which would probably work just fine iterating over the SimpleXML object.

Comment: @IMSoP I understand your words, The API accept XML (for example) `<root><b>1</b><b>2<b></root>` and also JSON that has same structure `{"b": ["1", "2"]}`. And it converts to array from XML/JSON before processing. API always can get data from array. but, I'd batter changing the converting logic (ex. convert JSON to SimpleXML object and get data from object). Thank you!